# Is there a way to schedule data exporting from Data-Studio to G-drive?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, looker-studio, drive

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64570231/datastudio-to-google-sheets) was never answered.

Do you know of any extension or script that allows scheduling data exporting from Data-Studio to G-drive?

What I have tried:

I create a table of fields, but I see no way to schedully export it just on off export.

[image]

Comment: There is no way to export data from Data Studio besides csv-export and to Sheets. The only backdoor could be a custumer visualisation, but I doubt you want to go that way. The easy approach is to export the google ads to big query, then do an export to gcs and from that to drive. Use a tool like airflow for building this pipeline.

Comment: Could you explain your use case a bit including what data source you are interested in? Data Studio is not meant to be used as a data processing or pipeline tool. If you have a specific data source, it might be more efficient to use some other tool to materialize the data on a regular basis. Also, I'll disagree with @Samuel : Community Visualization won't allow exporting data to Drive (See https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization/issues#limitations).

Comment: @MinhazKazi I'll double check. Thanks for that.  (1) DS also shows tables, so I've thought maybe they can be exported. (2) Off-topic, if I use DS<->G-Ads connector. Is there a way to intercept the underlying GAQL that formed a DS shown table (easy to detect GADs relevant APIs when you know only the field names).

Comment: @EladBenda (1) Yes, it shows the tables and the tables can be manually exported. But there is no automated way. (2) Unfortunately, you can't intercept the underlying requests in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can schedule to send the dashboard by email.

Data Studio is a visualization tool, you should not expect advanced export features.

If you use BigQuery, you can connect your Google Sheets direct to your data source. And if you don't use BigQuery, you should try.

Comment: Thanks (1) DS also shows tables, so I've thought maybe they can be exported. (2) Off-topic, if I use DS<->G-Ads connector. Is there a way to intercept the underlying GAQL that formed a DS shown table (easy to detect GADs relevant APIs when you know only the field names).

Comment: If you plan to manipulate Google Ads data, I don't understand why you're using Data Studio at all. There are several tools that connect to Google Ads to export data direct from the source. Export to BigQuery: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/adwords-transfer . Export to G Sheets: https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/9000139?hl=en